# Sorted Array of n square (n*n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, functional-programming

Input is n (any integer)

Output should be a
orted array of 
n square (n*n) , n , Closest Prime Number to n  , Closest Fibonacci number to n

How can I get the output?

Comment: You should really try to make a program to get to the solution. If you run into problems with that include it here with any error messages, or wrong (and expected) results you get

Answer (score 0):

Well this does seem to be pretty easy. First you have to calculate all these numbers.

n square is pretty straightforward so I'm not going to explain it.

For the prime number you start by checking `n` then you check `n-1` and `n+1` and so on until you find it.

For the Fibonacci number you have to calculate the series (which has for formula `F[i+1]=F[i]+F[i-1]`) until you go over `n`, then take the number closer to `n`.

Once you got everything you need to sort 4 numbers which is something I assume you can do.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

```
 public static int[] sortedSquaredArray(int[] array,int  n) {
    
            int[] result = new int[array.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                int sum=1;
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                   sum *= array[i] ;
                }
                result[i]=sum;
            }
            Arrays.sort(result);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Which question does this answer? I see no mention of `Prime` or `Fibonacci`. An `array` appears - wherefrom? You present your __`Solution`__ in a code block: Is there any particular programming language to interpret it?